# Find maximum difference in array

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an algorithm to return the **difference** of any pair of numbers, **such that the larger integer in the pair occurs at a higher index (in the array) than the smaller integer**.

Examples...

Array: [2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1]

Solution: 10 - 2 = 8

Output: 8

---

Array: [7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2]

Solution: 9 - 7 = 2

Output: 2

---

Here is what I have but it doesn't work for all tests...

```
var a = [22, 2, 4, 5, 6, 444, 1, 666];

// declare variables
var minNumber = a[0],                   // initilize to first element
    maxNumber = a[0],                   // --- ^
    minNumberIndex = 0,                 // min index
    maxNumberIndex = a.length - 1;      // max index

// loop through each element in array
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

    // find min
    if (a[i] < minNumber && i < maxNumberIndex) {
        minNumber = a[i];
        minNumberIndex = i;
    }

    // find max
    if (a[i] >= maxNumber && i > minNumberIndex) {
        maxNumber = a[i];
        maxNumberIndex = i;
    }
}

// return results
console.log("max: \t" + maxNumber);
console.log("min: \t" + minNumber + "index: " + minNumberIndex);
console.log(maxNumber - minNumber);
```

Please help!

Comment: can you please word it more clearly? Also what constitutes a pair? Will it be only of even length if the pair is two-two from beginning?'

Comment: 8 is not a pair, it's half a pair... it's confusing as to what you want, maybe at least add more example of desired outputs, and explain the pairs better.

Comment: the test cases/examples don't make sense... I don't understand the requirements.

Answer (score 8):

O(n) solution:

```js
function maxDifference(arr) {
  let maxDiff = -1;
  let min = arr[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > min && maxDiff < arr[i] - min) {
      maxDiff = arr[i] - min;
    }

    if (arr[i] < min) {
      min = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return maxDiff;
}

console.log(maxDifference([1, 2, 3])); //2
console.log(maxDifference(3, 2, 1)); //-1
console.log(maxDifference([2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1])); //8
console.log(maxDifference([7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2])); //2
console.log(maxDifference([22, 2, 4, 5, 6, 444, 1, 666])); //665
console.log(maxDifference([7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2])); //2
console.log(maxDifference([666, 555, 444, 33, 22, 23])); //1
console.log(maxDifference([2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1])); //8
```

Answer (score 6):

```
let MaxDifference = arr => {
  let maxDiff = null;
  for(let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
    for(let y = x+1; y < arr.length; y++){
        if(arr[x] < arr[y] && maxDiff < (arr[y] - arr[x])){
            maxDiff = arr[y] - arr[x]
        }
    }
  }
  return maxDiff === null ? -1 : maxDiff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have two arrays. Lets call them `minlr` and `maxrl`.

`minlr` - Where `minlr[i]` stores the minimum value till index `i` when going from left to right in the original array.

`maxrl` - Where `maxrl[i]` stores the maximum value till index `i` when going from right to left in the original array.

Once you have these 2 arrays, you iterate the arrays and find the max difference between `maxrl[i]` and `minlr[i]`.

In your above examples:

1. `minlr = {2,2,2,2,2,2,1};`

   `maxrl = {10,10,10,8,8,8,1};`

   So the answer in this case would be 10 - 2 = 8.
2. `minlr = {7,7,5,5,3,2};`

   `maxrl = {9,9,6,6,3,2};`

   So the answer in this case would be 9 - 7 = 2

Answer (score 1):

es6 version:

```
var a = [2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1];
var min = a[0];
var max = a[a.length-1];
var init = [[0,min], [a.length -1,max]];



var r = a.reduce((
            res, e,i
        )=>{
    var [[mini, min ], [maxi ,max]] = res;
    var t = res;
    if(e<min && i<maxi){
        t = [[i, e ], [maxi ,max]];
    }
    if(e>=max && i>mini){
       t = [[mini, min ], [i ,e]];
    }
    return t;
}, init);
console.log(r[1][1]-r[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok? for each item in the array, it looks at earlier items and adds the difference to the internal 'diffs' array (if the current item is greater). I then return the the largest value within the diffs array.

```
var findMaxDiff = function(arr){
    var diffs = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
                diffs.push(arr[i]-arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return Math.max.apply( Math, diffs );
}
```

Comment: (Looks OK to establish a *performance baseline*: should be difficult to find a solution using more operations without going out of one's way. For its straight-forwardness, it *may* be OK as an implementation to test against.)

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the array and using recursion like so:

```
function maxDifference(a){  
 var maxDiff = a[1] - a[0];  
  for(var i = 2; i<a.length-1; i++){
      var diff = a[i] - a[0];
      maxDiff = diff>maxDiff ? diff : maxDiff;
  }  
  if(a.length>1){
      a.shift();    
      var diff = maxDifference(a);
      maxDiff = diff>maxDiff ? diff : maxDiff;
  }

  return maxDiff;
}
        var x = [2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1];
        maxDifference(x); // returns 8
        x = [7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2];
    maxDifference(x) // returns 2
```

Comment: you might want to slice() before you shift(), so as not to destroy the original array... (maybe a=a.slice() up top?)

Answer (score 0):

In linear time and constant memory:

```
function maxDiff (nums) {
  var diff = 0, left = 0, right = 0, cur_right = 0, cur_left = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] < nums[cur_left]) {
      cur_left = i;
      if (cur_left > cur_right) {
        cur_right = cur_left;
      }
    }
    if (nums[i] >= nums[cur_right]) {
      cur_right = i;
    }
    if (nums[cur_right] - nums[cur_left] > diff) {
      diff = nums[cur_right] - nums[cur_left];
      right = cur_right;
      left = cur_left;
    }
  }
  return [diff, left, right];
}
```

If you're only interested in what the difference is, and not where the numbers occur, you don't need `left` and `right`.

Comment: i was toying with the idea of a non-recursive two-pass, but this "unrolls" them into one. very nice! i like.

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxDiff = function() {
  var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)[0];
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  if((list !== null) && (toString.call(list) !== "[object Array]")) {
    console.warn("not an array");
    return;
  }
  var maxDiff = list[1] - list[0];
  var min_element = list[0];
  var i, j;
  for(i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i] - min_element > maxDiff) {
      maxDiff = list[i] - min_element;
    }
    if(list[i] < min_element) {
      min_element = list[i];
    }
  }
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  var duration = end - start;
  console.log("time taken:: " + duration + "ms");
  return maxDiff;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
maxdiff = 0;
a =  [2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1]
for (i=a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for (j=i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (a[i] < a[j] ) continue;
    if (a[i] -a[j] > maxdiff) maxdiff = a[i] -a[j]
  }
}
console.log(maxdiff || 'No difference found')
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use es6 + es2020 latest feature to fix this issue

```js
function maxDiff(arr) {
 
 var diff=0
 if(arr?.length) diff=arr?.length?Math.max(...arr)-Math.min(...arr):0
 
  return diff;
}

console.log(maxDiff([1, 2, 3])); //2
console.log(maxDiff([3, 2, 1])); //2
console.log(maxDiff([2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1])); //9
console.log(maxDiff([7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2])); //7
console.log(maxDiff([22, 2, 4, 5, 6, 444, 1, 666])); //665
console.log(maxDiff([7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2])); //7
console.log(maxDiff([666, 555, 444, 33, 22, 23])); //644
console.log(maxDiff([-0, 1, 2, -3, 4, 5, -6])); //11
console.log(maxDiff([2])); //0
console.log(maxDiff([])); //0
```

Comment: `maxDiff([7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2])); //7` does not match example `Array: [7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2]

Solution: 9 - 7 = 2`: it fails to respect `the larger integer in the pair occurs at a higher index`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [22, 2, 4, 5, 6, 444, 1, 666];
function solution(a) {
    const max = Math.max.apply(null,a);
    const min = Math.min.apply(null,a);
    const diff = max-min;
    return diff
}
console.log(solution(a))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you actually don't need any looping, just use Math.max(), Math.min(), and [].indexOf() to do the heavy-lifting for you:

```
function findDiff(a){  
  var max=Math.max.apply(0, a),
    slot=a.lastIndexOf(max),
    min=Math.min.apply(0, a.slice(0, slot));
  if(a.length && !slot && !min-.153479 )return findDiff(a.slice(1));
  return max-min;
}

//ex: findDiff([7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2]) == 2
//ex: findDiff([666, 555, 444 , 33, 22, 23]) == 1
//ex: findDiff([2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1]) == 8
```

Comment: It fails for this array: [666, 555, 444 , 33, 22, 23]; It should return 1

Comment: 23-22=1. The problem needs to be solved for all arrays such that it returns the maximum difference between two elements such that larger element appears after the smaller number. In the sample I gave, 23 is larger than 22 and the difference is 1. Here's a link that explains the problem: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-difference-between-two-elements/

Comment: @Hoyen: yeah, kyle wasn't super clear and seems to have abandoned ship. i think you're right about returning the difference, my main point was using native methods to avoid un-needed loops and user-land comparisons... you have a different take than we did, and I hope your answer helps OP out, if he's still alive. i do appreciate your follow up.

Comment: I tried to undo the down vote, but it won't let me without fixing your answer. Sorry for doing that.

Comment: @Hoyen: edited to use my orig ideas on a solution that works, now that i understand it because of your help.

Comment: `!min-.153479`?????? Also this iterates over the array multiple times and super unreadable.

Comment: So you can replace looping by recursion.