# How to find i and j indeces of an array where A[j] - A[i] is the maximum value and i < j?

Tags: algorithm, max

I have found many solutions for this problem but the time complexity turns out to be O(n^2). I'm trying to find solution with time complexity of O(n).
The solutions I saw there: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-difference-between-two-elements/ works fine, but how to get the numbers indeces and do not make it more complex?
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: If you can find the numbers in O(n), you can also find their indices in O(n) by just searching for them afterwards. But it should not be that hard to adapt the code to keep track of the indices along the way.

Comment: [This question is answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585679/find-maximum-difference-in-array)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works:

- iterate the array tracking the index for the minimum value thus far (O(n))

  - for each index insert an entry into a map: index -> currMinIdx
  - update currMinIdx with the current value if necessary
- you now have a map of the minimum value index associated with each index
- iterate that map and determine the highest difference (O(n))

in pseudocode:

```
//init variables
int currMinIdx = -1
map<Int, Int> maxIdxToMinIdxMap // a map of the index of the min value for a given index

//iterate the array to populate the map
for every i in A:    
    maxToMinIdxMap[i] = currMinIdx
    if A[i] < A[currMinIdx]:
        currMinIdx = i


int currMinIdx2 = -1
int currMaxIdx2 = -1
int currMaxDiff

for every entry in maxIdxToMinIdxMap:
     if A[entry.key] - A[entry.value] > currMaxDiff:
          currMaxDiff = A[entry.key] - A[entry.value]
          currMaxIdx2 = entry.key
          currMinIdx2 = entry.value
```

Comment: Now looking at the link you posted, I believe this corresponds to method two.